# If Statement AutoFilter meets criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to make an `If Statement` that will only run if my list meets a certain criterion. However, right now the macro runs even though my `AutoFilter` criteria do not include `4` in `Criteria1`.

Would anyone know how to correct this issue?

```
Private Sub FilterAndPaste()    
  Sheets(1).Select

  If ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$M$807").AutoFilter(Field:=2, Criteria1:="4") Then


        ' Insert the VLOOKUP formula into the given range
        ActiveSheet.Range("M3").Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=VLOOKUP(RC[-9],'[TestFile.xlsm]Test'!C1:C13,12,0)"
            ActiveSheet.Range("M3").Offset(1, -1).Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
                Selection.FillDown

        ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Example").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Rows("4:100").RowHeight = 12
    Else
        End
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two questions and I will try and answer them accordingly.

> Q1. Right now the macro runs even though my AutoFilter criteria do not include 4 in Criteria1. Would anyone know how to correct this issue?

That is because the moment you say

`If ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$M$807").AutoFilter(Field:=2, Criteria1:="4") Then`

Excel will put an autofilter and your condition will be true.

> Q2. I am currently trying to make an If Statement that will only run if my list meets a certain criterion.

To check for the criteria use this

```
With Sheets(1)
    If .AutoFilterMode = True And .FilterMode = True Then
        Debug.Print .Range("$A$3:$M$807").Parent.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria1
    End If
End With
```

Something like this

```
With Sheets(1)
    If .AutoFilterMode = True And .FilterMode = True Then
        If .Range("$A$3:$M$807").Parent.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria1 = "=4" Then
            '
            '~~> Rest of the code
            '
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Sid, is the question "does the filter include the criteria", or is it "is there a line in the list that meets the criteria", calling for either a `subtotal(3` or a specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)` solution?

Comment: @nutsch: There are 2 questions. Q1. `I am currently trying to make an If Statement that will only run if my list meets a certain criterion.` Q2. `right now the macro runs even though my AutoFilter criteria do not include 4 in Criteria1. Would anyone know how to correct this issue?` I answered both... Why it is happening and how to achieve what OP wants

Comment: I have updated the answer so it will be more clear now :) @nutsch

Comment: @SiddharthRout When I try to run that and step into the code, it will skip all the code when it hits the `If .AutoFilterMode = True And .FilterMode = True Then` line. If I take that out, and only run `If .Range("$A$3:$M$807").Parent.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria1 = "=4" Then` I get a `run-time '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error` Any idea as to why?

Comment: t is skipping because there is no autofilter applied.

Comment: Ok got it. I fixed that, any idea for the `run-time 1004`?

Comment: I just tested the code. It doesn't give me any error. Whether the criteria is 4 or not.

Comment: Ensure that there is a filter applied. Do not delete any line from my code. You may add code in between though...